# iOS 11 Bug: UINavigationBar items not being set / being set incorrectly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, ios11, xcode9

I've been dealing with a slew of issues regarding iOS since its release >_<

This one might be the strangest so far: UIBarButtonItem's are showing up with the wrong width and height (and color).

[image]
The wide-blue-box on the left is the `leftBarButtonItem` with the `.width` being set to 100. The thin box inside of it is the new `_UIModernBarButton` that has a height of 2px. It's supposed to say "Reset" in a blue color but only shows up as blue if you tap on it (or try to)

The tall-thing-box on the right side is the `rightBarButtonItem` without being setting the `.width` property. It's basically impossible to tap.

If anyone else has been experiencing any similar bugs due to changes in iOS 11 and have found any workarounds, you're feedback would be very very helpful!

UPDATE:
I've found that this only happens when I `initWithTitle:` It seems to be working just fine with custom views, images, and system items.

Comment: Are you creating everything in a storyboard or code?

Comment: @theMikeSwan everything is in code

Comment: I would suggest editing your question to include the code you are using, someone might spot an issue that you haven't seen. Feel free to alter the names of things as needed and there is no need for the action methods themselves to be shown.